# print word document in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i need to print word.activedocument from vb.net.
i can do that with **document.printout().** but i need print that document nto specific tray of the printer. 
so now i am using **printdocument.print()** becuse with this line of command i can define the specific pagesorce to print from, but i don know how to cast or assign my word document to this printdocument.print???
here is my code if my question is confusing

Dim oWord As Word.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim app As Word.Document = oWord.ActiveDocument
        Dim objDataTypeMetafile As New Object
        objDataTypeMetafile = Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteMetafilePicture
        '   oWord.Visible = True
        Dim num_copies As String = tb_num_copies.Text
        'oWord.PrintOut(Copies:=num_copies, PrintToFile:=False)

```
    Dim prtdoc As New PrintDocument
    Dim strDefaultPrinter As String = prtdoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName
    Dim strPrinter As String
    For Each strPrinter In PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
        com_printer.Items.Add(strPrinter)

        If strPrinter = strDefaultPrinter Then
            com_printer.SelectedIndex = com_printer.Items.IndexOf(strPrinter)
        End If

        Dim pkSource As Printing.PaperSource
        Dim printDoc As New PrintDocument
        ' AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage 

        printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = strPrinter
        For Each pkSource In printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources
            If pkSource.RawKind = "261" Then


                printDoc.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource.RawKind = pkSource.RawKind
                Dim psize As Printing.PaperSize = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Item(5)
                printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = PrintRange.AllPages
                'AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintDoc_PrintPage
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = num_copies
                printDoc.PrinterSettings.Duplex = Duplex.Default

                AddHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler

                printDoc.Print()

                RemoveHandler printDoc.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler

            End If

        Next

    Next strPrinter
    oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
??????????????????
end sub

Comment: You just can't use PrintDocument, that's only available to create your own prints.  You must use the printing support built into Word.  And deal with its limitation.

Comment: YOU CAN NOT DO THAT WITH printdocument.print(). but you can specify the trays in printout(). like while saying firstrayprint= "" and otherprinttray="" ...